# Show log of only branches and merges

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, is it possible to create a repository log which only only shows branch and merge history? i.e., any other commits would be excluded?

If possible, this would present a higher-level view of project history which may be useful in some circumstances (such as training others).

The ideal would be to have a graphical log output of this (such as in TortoiseHg).

Answer (score 3):

[Revsets](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#specifying-revision-sets) are so powerful. May be showing the `merge()` changesets or its parents.

```
$ hg log -G -T "{rev} {branch}" -r "merge() or merge()^1 or merge()^2"
```

Gives something like

```
o    296 stable
|\
| o    295 test
| |\
| | @  294 default
| | |
o | |  292 stable
| | |
o | |  290 stable
|\| |
| o |  289 test
| |\|
| | o  288 default
| | |
| o |  287 test
| |\|
| | o  286 default
| | |
| o |  284 test
| |\|
| | o  283 default
...
o |  30 stable
|\|
o |  29 stable
| |
| o  28 default
| |
| o  27 default
|/|
o |  26 stable
|/
o  4 default
|
```

The *only commit* changesets are hidden.

Answer (score -1):

> repository log which only only shows branch and merge history?

Yes. `hg help revsets`

> The ideal would be to have a graphical log output of this

```
hg log -G -r "REVSET"
```

Comment: You may be on the right track, but some more specific guidance would really help. I have tried the "branchpoint() or merge()" revset but it returns all sorts of other changesets which are neither.

Comment: @DaveInCaz - for "more specific guidance" you have to describe more detailled requirements, like "branch X and merges of this branch into all other branches|merges to X"

Comment: I'm confused what is unclear in the original question. I'd like to filter out anything other than a branch or a merge. This would not be particular to my own repository. Your answer suggested revsets but did not include a specific way of doing this.